# WebStorm find all places where component is used, where certain prop is NOT passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I want to search through my react codebase for all the instances where I'm rendering a component `ExampleComponent`. This component has a property that is not required `exampleprop`.

Now I want to find all the usages of this component where `exampleprop` is NOT passed.

Can this somehow be achieved?

**Examples that should be included in the search matches (because `exampleprop` is not passed)**

```
<ExampleComponent
 prop1={"test"}
 prop2={2}
/>
```

```
<ExampleComponent prop1={"test"} />
```

**Examples that should *NOT* be included in the search matches (because `exampleprop` *is* passed)**

```
<ExampleComponent
 prop1={"test"}
 exampleprop={"test2"}
 prop2={2}
/>
```

```
<ExampleComponent prop1={"test"} exampleprop={"test2"} />
```

I'm using WebStorm.

Comment: A search regex could maybe be an option, like `<ExampleComponent(\s*(prop1|prop2)=[^}]+}\s*)+\/>` (try [here](https://regex101.com/r/NrUQ8l/1))

Comment: @philipphutterer Nice solution, there can however be many more different props other than `prop1` and `prop2`

Comment: Since they are finite, you may add all of them in the regex.

Comment: Have a look at SSR (Structural Search and Replace) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html#share_template . Sadly I have no idea how well it will work with React code... or how to check that specific prop is NOT present, although I do remember trying it with some success to find all HTML `button` elements where `aria-xxx` attribute was missing (too bad I do not remember which project was that and what pattern I have used back then to check it now).

Comment: @LazyOne I actually just discovered this feature yesterday. I unfortunately find that the documentation of this feature is very limited, which I find strange since it seems like a very powerful tool.